3528 RGB LED common anode but + on pin 1
I have a gaming controller (nacon; mid tier) which have 3 damaged LEDs. They are 4 pin RGB LED 3528 size in common anode. But the positive common is on pin 1 (the LED marked pin) and all the LEDs online shows a pinout like this. Anyone got a clue about the orientation? 


Here is a common anode on pin 1:  https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/150141M173100/4489960  If that isn't what you're looking for, include a diagram of the pad.

I think there is no standard, the pin numbering on the link you gave is different (it is infact the same as above when you look at the cut marking). On the led of the joystick, the cut marked pin is +ve (thats pin 3 in the link you gave). I have added a drawing of what I'm looking for

If your controller LED's are damaged, are you really SURE that the LED that you need has this odd pinout? I googled a lot and didn't find a LED with this particular pinout. Does it seem probable that a mid tier vendor would use an odd component, out of the industry's standards?

I checked the polarity multiple times and also it is common anode LED or not. The controller is actually a Nacon revolution pro 3 wired controller; I think that's a decent brand. I also checked a lot and so I ended up having to ask for help. I really don't know why they would do such a thing. Anyway to clear your doubt will definitely make a video and give a link (3 of 4 leds are damaged, 1 is still good). I know it's kind of unbelievable.

https://youtu.be/JuRznpuReg4?feature=shared   sorry for the bad quality. I don't usually record videos I just used phone.
